# Редактирование разделов блочных устройств

Tags: linux, partition

Прошу подсказать каким образом можно производить манипуляции с разделами блочных устройств.

Есть, например, флешка, подключенная  как /dev/sdb. На ней есть какие-то разделы sdb1 и sdb2 например. Как программно модифицировать разделы этого устройства? Скажем, удалить эти 2 раздела, создать в неразмеченном пространстве новый загрузочный раздел (с флагом esp и boot), и еще, например, 2 для файлов.

Где-то слышал высказывание, мол "В UNIX всё - это файл". Вот и в системном каталоге /sys/block есть различная информация о блочных устройствах.

Собственно, отсюда и вопрос. Достаточно ли простой модификации этих файлов для перезаписи информации о разделах устройства?

К сожалению, простой гуглежкой результатов особо добиться не удалось, так как на запросы вроде "linux edit device partition" предлагается в основном уже написанный софт для подобных вещей (вроде fdisk, cgdisk и т.п.)

Так что может кто знает где об этом всем можно подробнее почитать? Желательно на английском. Или же примеры кода (какой язык - неважно), где подобное реализуется.

Comment: *"В UNIX всё - это файл"* — ну, во-первых, *gnu* — это «**not** unix», а во-вторых, увы, подойти ближе к этому идеалу разработчики смогли только [в «unix номер 2», она же «план девять»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9), в-третьих же стоит упомянуть, что sysfs — это, фактически, «утащенная» как раз из plan9 фича. но без всех остальных фич это, скорее, огрызок, а не фича.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Почитать подробнее можно [тут FHS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html).

В каталоге /sys содержится информация об устройствах и драйверах, и некоторые функции ядра (к примеру можно перечитать свойства устройства). Пример кода можно как раз посмотреть в репозиториях  [parted](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parted.git), [cfdisk](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/disk-utils/cfdisk.c) там это реализуется.

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю, это то, что нужно.

Comment: @smellyshovel, нет, там манипуляции производятся не через интерфейс sysfs, а [«старыми добрыми» ioctl-ами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl).